# referencing fragment EditText contents in main activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am building an Android app where i need to get user inputs to store general settings in a configuration file. One of the settings is the server IP address.

I have designed a fragment layout (separate ServerIPfragment.java file) associated with an XML layout file fragment_serverip.xml) that includes two EditText to capture server IP and port number. There are also two buttons to save or cancel the entry.

The save button does the following and the saveServerIP function is defined in MainActivity.java:

```
public void saveServerIP(View v) {
    String serverIP = "123.123.123.123";//this works and pops up the Toast msg
    String serverIP etServerIP.getText().toString();// this crashes the app

    if (MyIpMatch.isValidIP(serverIP)) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "IP address is valid!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "IP address is not valid!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

I build the reference to the EditText in MainActivity.java as follows:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
EditText etServerIP;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // get reference to the views        
    etServerIP = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fieldServerIP);
}
```

Then I go to the fragment view through a menu option as follows:

```
if (id == R.id.action_changeIP) {
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_serverip);
```

Once I update the EditText fieldServerIP and click the Save button, the code works fine if I use a fixed string but I cannot seem to get the contents of the EditText to use it in the ip validator.

The ip validator is also in the MainActivity file

What am I doing wrong? how can I store the EditText contents in the fragment to a String variable so I can pass it to the ip validator code in  MainActivity.java?

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work without using a listener. Not sure it is the right way, but it works... feel free to comment about any risk with my implementation of the fragment...

1. right-click on the main activity java file to add a fragment (not on the folder as I have read somewhere)
2. enter the following entry in the main activity XML file

Note that if I do not enclose the fragment in a FrameLayout, it crashes - the reason is probably obvious to java experts but not to the novice that I am in Java coding.

I made no changes to the Java file generated in step 1

3. Design your layout for the fragment
4. call the fragment view as follows - I did it in a menu option in the MainActivity:

@Override

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {        
int id = item.getItemId();
//noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
    return true;
}
if (id == R.id.action_changeIP) {
    //
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_server_setup);
return true;
```

6. my layout had 2 EditText fields and a "Save" button
7. define a saveSettings function in your main activity and attach it to the onClick event for your button, something like (sorry couldn't get the code formatting to work...):

   public void saveServerIP(View v) {

   etServerIP = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fieldServerIP);

   if (MainActivity.MyIpMatch.isValidIP(etServerIP.getText().toString())) {

   Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "IP is valid!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

   ```
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   ```

   } else {
       Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "IP is not valid!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
   }

Note that I first set a reference to the EditText and then used that reference in the ip validator to be able to use getText().

Success, the app doesn't crash and pops the Toast msg. That should mean I can do whatever I need to do with the fragment elements.

I do have one question though: once I switch back to the main activity layout, the button I defined there no longer works instantly, i.e. the HTTP request that it should be triggering is bot working for a couple minutes. If I restart the app, it will again work instantly. Any idea what might be causing this? do I need to add some code to do a clean switch between views?